# Python 3.5 on Windows in Bluetooth context. The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: android, python, windows, bluetooth, bluez

Code is as follows:

```
from bluetooth import *
import sys

if sys.version < '3':
    input = raw_input

addr = None

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("no device specified.  Searching all nearby bluetooth devices for")
    print("the SampleServer service")
else:
    addr = sys.argv[1]
    print("Searching for SampleServer on %s" % addr)

# search for the SampleServer service
addr = "CC:79:4A:4B:35:85"
service_matches = find_service( address = addr )

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("couldn't find the SampleServer service =(")
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

print("connecting to \"%s\" at Address - %s on Port %d" % (name, host, port))

# Create the client socket
sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))

print("connected.  type stuff")
while True:
    data = input()
    if len(data) == 0: break
    sock.send(data)

sock.close()
```

Run time error thrown as follows:

```
no device specified.  Searching all nearby bluetooth devices for
the SampleServer service
connecting to "None" at Address - CC:79:4A:4B:35:85 on Port 31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T_C_1.py", line 40, in <module>
    sock.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 72, in connect
    bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError: The requested address is not valid in its context.
```

I am unable to figure out why. Some sites tell me that my Host address need to be on the local machine....
This code resides and is run from my WIndows machine in an attempt to connect to an Android phone over Bluetooth.
I don't get why / how...
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have run across the same error using PyBluez on Windows since I had to leave my Mac environment after receiving a bind error. I found out that the issue comes about when you are binding to a foreign IP address, or one that isn't known by your system(e.g outside public IPs). Try creating a server in PyBluez with the addr of '' and attempt to connect to that. We can further diagnose your problem from there if that doesn't work. Sorry for it not being a solid answer, I'm new to StackOverflow and I couldn't exactly comment but I wanted to offer some help.